# Difference between stream conversion and stream copy in C#

Tags: c#, stream

I  have following code for creating a byte array from stream in my project

```
Stream originalStream = something;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   originalStream.CopyTo(ms);
   var data = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Also I have

```
var data = ((MemoryStream)originalStream).ToArray();
```

Is there any major differences in these two code. I think the first code, creates an additional MemoryStream and copies the stream contents.

But the direct type conversion does the same ?. Does the second code makes more performance ?

Comment: If the source stream is a `MemoryStream` then the second one is both faster an allocates less memory since it avoids the copy as you've surmised, but that won't work if it is a `NetworkStream` or `FileStream` or any other stream that doesn't inherit from `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Yes, the originalStream is ```MemoryStream``` , but when invoking this function, just using ```Stream ``` base

Comment: Try `File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "Hello"); (MemoryStream)File.OpenRead("test.txt");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one will throw [`InvalidCastException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception?view=net-7.0):

```cs
Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"...");
var stream = (MemoryStream)fileStream; // InvalidCastException
```

If the stream is a `MemoryStream` it will be more performant since you will not perform extra copying and just cast the stream object to actual type.

To prevent invalid cast exception you can [type test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) the incoming parameter, for example:

```cs
if (originalStream is MemoryStream ms)
{
    // use ms
}
else
{
   // perform the copying
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be note that the default `Stream.CopyTo` method copies the data based on its position, so if you don't reset the position of the input stream, the destination stream will be empty.

```
var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
var ms2 = new MemoryStream();
ms1.WriteByte(1);
ms1.WriteByte(2);
ms1.CopyTo(ms2);
Console.WriteLine(ms1.ToArray().Length); // 2
Console.WriteLine(ms2.ToArray().Length); // 0
```